# Sending quoted string to javascript function, then to php

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to send a string containing single and double quotes to a javascript function which then sends it to a php page as a get variable. The code is this (I've tried escaping the quotes in two ways, but none of them work):

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction (foo) {
      window.location = "bar.php?var=" + foo;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <a href='javascript:myFunction("text&#39;text&#34;text");'>text'text"text</a><br>
  <a href='javascript:myFunction("text&apos;text&quot;text");'>text'text"text</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The links just don't have any effect.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the value before echoing it onto the page

```
<a href='javascript:myFunction(<?php echo urlencode($value); ?>);'><?php echo $value; ?></a>
```

Comment: I tried
  <?php
    echo "<a href='javascript:myFunction(" . urlencode("text'text\"text") . ");'>test1</a><br>
 <a href='javascript:myFunction(" . urlencode('text\'text"text') . ");'>test2</a><br>";
  ?>
That doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

`urlencode` *** is the correct syntax

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
echo '<a href="bar.php?var='.urlencode($value).'">text\'text"text</a><br>';
```